# Align <a> in the middle of other <a> with white-space: wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a nav with li and a elements. I have one a with the name "Quem Somos" and other with "Educação e Carreira", but this last one has white-space: wrap. The alignment of all elements is being taking in the first word, in this case, "Quem somos" is align horizontally with "Educação e".

My doubt is if is possible to align the a "Quem Somos" in the middle of "Educação e Carreira", which has wrap rule. Like, the align will take place between the wrap.
[Current alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhgxw.png) I just want to align the non-wrap text relate with the wrap text.

[How I want to align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qfUO.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device- 
    width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min. 
       css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav navbar navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav align-items-center" id="ul-nav">
          <!--<li><a class="nav-link"  href="index.html">Home</a></li>-->
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="quemsomos.html">Quem Somos</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" id="educacao" href="educacao_carreira.html">Educação e <br>Carreira</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="http://proepi.org.br/comunidade" target="_blank">Comunidade<br> de Prática</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="transparencia.html">Transparência</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, add your code to the question, then we can help you.

Comment: Can we see some code? Is the `a`-tag inside another `a`-tag? If so, thats invalid HTML

Comment: Please share some code, HTML & CSS or whatever you have done.

Comment: I'll paste the code

Comment: But, the question is not about the code, I just wanna to know if there is some way in CSS to align a text in the middle of other text who has a white-space or a br. In this case, I want to align the "Quem Somos" in the middle of "Educação e Carreira", between the "Educação e" and "Carreira"

Comment: @TallesSilva the thing is that we don't done what you have done or how is it looking extactly just by telling us; its easier if we can actually *see* what you mean

Comment: This is the actual state:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhgxw.png

Comment: "*the question is not about the code*" - then this really isn't the right place to be asking. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean it, I know you need some code, but I put other pictures in the description that will make things clear.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant CSS as well?

Comment: <a class="nav-link" href="transparencia.html" style="
    top:  8px;
">Transparência</a>

<a class="nav-link" href="quemsomos.html" style="
    top: 8px;
">Quem Somos</a>

Comment: The only way I figured out to fix this problem, but I'm not sure if the align is exactly in the middle.

Comment: You are using Bootstrap... correct?

Comment: Yes, Boostrap, I've tried to put the entire code in the description, but not worked.

Comment: @TallesSilva look at my answer

Comment: Yes, but I've tried to do the same here and did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems you are using Bootstrap, if so, you just add a `align-items-center` class to the `navbar-nav` `ul` and you should get the alignment you expect.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav align-items-center" id="ul-nav">
      <!--<li><a class="nav-link"  href="index.html">Home</a></li>-->
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="quemsomos.html">Quem Somos</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" id="educacao" href="educacao_carreira.html">Educação e <br>Carreira</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="http://proepi.org.br/comunidade" target="_blank">Comunidade<br> de Prática</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="transparencia.html">Transparência</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- This is the same code you provided without the class I added -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark mt-5">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ul-nav">
      <!--<li><a class="nav-link"  href="index.html">Home</a></li>-->
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="quemsomos.html">Quem Somos</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" id="educacao" href="educacao_carreira.html">Educação e <br>Carreira</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="http://proepi.org.br/comunidade" target="_blank">Comunidade<br> de Prática</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="transparencia.html">Transparência</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The code in your question, fixed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device- 
width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- You had spaces between bootstrap.min. and css -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Add navbar-expand to the nav -->
  <nav class="nav navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-success">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav align-items-center" id="ul-nav">
          <!--<li><a class="nav-link"  href="index.html">Home</a></li>-->
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="quemsomos.html">Quem Somos</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" id="educacao" href="educacao_carreira.html">Educação e <br>Carreira</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="http://proepi.org.br/comunidade" target="_blank">Comunidade<br> de Prática</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="transparencia.html">Transparência</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Then you have additional CSS that's conflicting with Boostrap classes; I literally just added the class to the code you provided

Comment: @TallesSilva Did you left out relevant code in your example? I see you only provided the `collapse` portion of you navbar; did you include that in an actual `navbar` container as Bootstrap requires? This is the reason why we ask you to provide all the relevant code, because depending on what you have on your file our solutions might or might not work; please provide all the code so we can replicate your issue *exactly* as you see it

Comment: I update the description with the code I'm using and not working.

Comment: You are not closing tags correctly, thats why you don't see it working; you have to close another `div` tag before the `nav` tag... Also you had spaces in the link for the Bootstrap stylesheet; I fixed that as well